# navbar problem when shrinking to dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

My Top Navbar run perfectly in dekstop/PC display but when it shrink to mobile display, the dropdown menu go wrong.

4 bars menu are on the left, and 1 bar on right. When the navbar collapse become dropdown, menu still divided on the left and right.
Here is my code.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li class="btnMenu clickable" id="btnHome"><a>Home</a></li>
        <li class="btnMenu clickable" id="btn2"><a>bar1</a></li>
        <li class="btnMenu clickable" id="btn3"><a>bar2</a></li>
        <li class="btnMenu clickable" id="btn4"><a>bar3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="logout.php" class="clickable"><p>Sign Out as <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]);?></b></p></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want the dropdown menu vertically fused (the sign out button below the bar3).

Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you try creating it for the mobile first and later using media queries build it for a desktop?

Comment: are you using bootstrap? which version?

Comment: @CodeBlaze https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js